# SQL server error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'False' to data type int"

Tags: sql-server

Greetings im trying to join these 2 tables to find some data for a report im creating and im getting the error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'False' to data type int. Any idea why this is happening? I cant spot where i wrote wrong the code.!! any answer would be welcomed!!!

```
SELECT L.CUSTNO, CUST_NAME1, CUST_NAME2, CUST_NAME3
   ,CUST_NAME4, L.BRANCH, REFER_NO
   ,RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, L.CUSTNO), 6) + ' - '
      +CAST(LOAN_PRODUCT AS CHAR(4))  + ' - ' 
      +RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, LOAN_ACC_SEQ_NO), 2) ACC_STR
   ,[CHECK_PRIN], [L_PRIN], [L_INT], [L_INTLQ], [L_EXP], [L_ACCR]
   ,[INV_BILL_CHARG_AMT], [P_PRIN], [P_INT], [P_OTH], [P_EXP]
   ,[P_PRV_S_INT], [P_ACCRUED], [P_OFF_ACCR]
FROM BleckBase1.dbo.[lm-loanacc] AS L
join BleckBase1.dbo.[lm-CUSTOMERMF] AS C ON L.CUSTNO = C.CUSTNO
WHERE ToClose = 0
```

Comment: Without more information, we can't really help... can you post the schemas of both tables? What are the possible values of `ToClose`?

Comment: Maybe it's not related to the Q, but **always** specify the length of `N/VARCHAR(n)`

Comment: I see 2 possibilities.  Perhaps `ToClose` is varchar but you're comparing to `0` which is int.  This might be fixed by `WHERE ToClose = '0'`, comparing to string 0 instead of int 0.  The 2nd possibility I see is `CUSTNO`.  You would get this error if one of `L.CUSTNO` and `C.CUSTNO` is int while the other is varchar.

Comment: best way to trouble shoot these is to remove all the casts and converts and reintroduce one at a time to see where the error is coming from